# What is a "Variant of type (Error)"?

Tags: delphi, ole

I have this working piece of code accessing an Outlook [AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869865.aspx) method:

```
var
  lPropertyAccessor: OLEVariant;
  lDT              : TDateTime;
  lSchemas, lValues: Variant;

lPropertyAccessor := AAppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor;
lSchemas := VarArrayOf([cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLID + 'fail',
                        cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCTIME,
                        cPublicStringNameSpace + PROPERTY_TIMETELLSYNCID]);
try
  lValues := lPropertyAccessor.GetProperties(lSchemas);
  lEvent.CustSyncTTID := lValues[0];
  lDT := lValues[1];
  lDT := TTimeZone.Local.ToLocalTime(lDT);
  lEvent.CustSyncDate := lDT;
  lEvent.CustSyncEntryID := lValues[2];
except
end;
```

I am causing this to fail for the first array entry ("  + 'fail' "), because I want to test what the documentation says:
`If an error occurs for getting a specific property, the Err value will be returned in the corresponding location in the returned array.`

After calling GetProperties, according to the inspector window, lValues[0] contains: Error(-2147221233).

I have tried to find a Windows named constant with this value so that I can test against it (if lValues[0] <> MagicalWindowsConst then...), but I can't find it or its hex equivalent FFFFFFFF8004010F (not even in the Embarcadero source files).

If I let the code continue, the integer assignment for lEvent.CustSyncTTID gives:
'Could not convert variant of type (Error) into type (Integer)'

That would suggest there is some 'error' variant type??? I can't find that either.

I tried defining `const cErr = -2147221233` or `const cErr : Int64 = -2147221233` but that gives me an Invalid Variant Operation error on the `if lValues[0] <> cErr`.

What can I test against to determine if the array element returns the error code?

Comment: If we break down the `HRESULT` we see that the leading `8` indicates failure, `SEVERITY_ERROR`, the facility is `4`, `FACILITY_ITF` and the code is `0x010F`. `FACILITY_ITF` means "The actual meaning of the error is defined by the interface. That is, two HRESULTs with exactly the same 32-bit value returned from two different interfaces might have different meanings." You are using Outlook and that error from Outlook is "Outlook data file cannot be accessed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it:

I can test `if VarType(lValues[0]) <> varError`

So I obviously overlooked that there [is a varError type](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=VarType)

Comment: FWIW, there's also [VarIsError](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Variants_VarIsError@Variant.html)

Comment: Thanks for pasting the solution. It just helped me too!